# PyQt5: How can i add a placeholder and input mask simultaneously

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing a chat application created using the PyQt5 library and QtDesigner. I have created a QLineEdit object called birthdayInput to retrieve the user's birth data, which will be put into a database in the future. I would like the birthdayInput object to force the user to type the date in YYYY-MM-DD format, while also containing a Placeholder with an instruction caption, such as "Enter your date of birth". However, when I try to do this, only two "- -" characters are displayed instead of the Placeholder. In addition, the user has to "move the cursor" to the beginning himself, instead of automatically giving this cursor to the beginning of the text.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from datetime import datetime

import login


class RegisterWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi('registrationPageUIScreen.ui', self)

        self.setWindowTitle("ChatApp")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('chatAppLogo.png'))

        self.setFixedSize(520, 600)

        self.birthdayInput.setInputMask('9999-99-99')
        self.birthdayInput.setPlaceholderText('Birthday Input')

        self.createAccountButton.clicked.connect(self.register)
        self.loginButton.clicked.connect(self.open_login_window)

    def register(self):
        username = self.nameInput.text()
        surname = self.surnameInput.text()
        birthday = self.birthdayInput.text()
        email = self.emailInput.text()
        password = self.passwordInput.text()
        usercountry = self.countryInput.currentText()
        againpassword = self.againPasswordInput.text()

    def open_login_window(self):
        self.login_window = login.LoginWindow()
        self.login_window.show()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register_app = QApplication([])
    register_window = RegisterWindow()
    register_window.show()
    register_app.exec_()
```

I tried every method that seemed to make sense to me. I searched on the internet, took exceptional help from ChatGpt, but nothing helped.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a [QRegExpValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html).